# Error with installing LIBSVM on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-12.04, libsvm

I'm trying to install LIBSVM on UBUNTU 12.04 Desktop edition but it doesn't work. I have tried so many way and I read all the instructions in the READ ME file but still doesn't work and give me the error after writing `make` in the command window. I did the `mex -setup` and then it gives me two options which I have tried both of them, it goes fine but after that step when I write make or make.m I got this error.

```
Warning: You are using gcc version "4.4.7-1ubuntu2)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.2.3".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/


mex:  libsvmread.c  not a normal file or does not exist.
```

If make.m fails, please check README about detailed instructions.

By the way, I have installed the libsvm 3.17 in different locations but I still get the same error.

Comment: two things: did you notice the warning about gcc version, and did you try `make` from bash shell (there is a Makefile in `matlab` folder, you might have to adjust the location of where MATLAB is installed)?

Comment: about the gcc? yeah, it's fully installed and upgraded.. but can you explain more about the second question?

Comment: @Amro this were the matlab is installed /home/mario/Matlab

Comment: I meant your MATLAB version officially supports gcc 4.2.3 whereas you have a newer version installed. You might need to get the older gcc, not sure.. As the to second point, try running `MATLABDIR=/path/to/matlab make` from the shell to compile the MEX-files (of course use the actual path to matlab instead), this is explained in the README file

Comment: It didn't work the second way, I will try to install an older version and to see what will happen .....

Comment: what was the error when compiling with the Makefile?

Comment: the errors that you see above @Amro

Comment: Im not sure whats wrong, it should be straightforward to compile.. For example see the steps explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15559516/97160) (I realize that was for Windows, but the process is basically the same)

Comment: @Amro I guess because I have an old version of Matlab which is 2010a and my ubuntu is 12.04