# How to use libsvm to get probability output

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I would like to use -b option in LIBSVM and could not find an example usage in Matlab. When I try to write this:

```
svmtrain(bow, [1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0], '-b 1');
```

I get "Wrong number of arguments" error. When I remove '-b 1' from arguments, in the svmpredict I only get 0 or 1 in result. I want the probability result. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svmtrain function you are calling is not libsvm - it's Matlab's statistics toolbox svmtrain.m!

Use `which svmtrain`to see which file is actually called. Make sure that you used libsvm's `make` to compile the necessary libsvm mex files and that they are in Matlab's path. In my installation, I renamed libsvm's svmtrain and svmpredict mex files to libsvm_svmtrain and libsvm_svmpredict in order to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: I have dowloaded and put libsvm into my workspace directory. How can i compile those mex files in windows? is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: Look for make.m in the libsvm\Matlab folder. There's also a readme file there.

Comment: After I go into /libsvm-master/matlab directory, in matlab I called "make" command and all MEXs completed succesfully. However, still when I use shich svmtrain, it shows matlab statistics toolbox. how to change that? sorry for multiple problems

Comment: If the mex files are there, I guess that path isn't right. Make sure that libsvm-master/matlab directory itself is added to your path. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557908/how-to-run-libsvm-in-matlab

Comment: As you have done I have changed the name as libsvm_train etc.and it worked